# How to apply a HeaderTemplateProperty to a HeaderProperty inside in a CustomControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

In the `MyCustomControl`, I created the `Heder` and `HeaderTemplate` dependency properties.

```cs
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register(
                   "Header",
                   typeof(object),
                   typeof(MyCustomControl),
                   new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                           (object)null,
                           new PropertyChangedCallback(OnHeaderChanged)));


    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTemplateProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
             "HeaderTemplate",
             typeof(DataTemplate),
             typeof(MyCustomControl),
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                     (DataTemplate)null,
                     new PropertyChangedCallback(OnHeaderTemplateChanged)));

    private static void OnHeaderTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ???;
    }
```

I don’t understand what I have to write for `HeaderTemplate` to apply to `Header`. I think it needs to be written here `OnHeaderTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)`, but what exactly?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: No, it needs to be done in the XAML. The ContentControl or ContentPresenter which displays Header needs to use the HeaderTemplate property. Please show the XAML for your custom control.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the XAML there, as text. Thanks!

Comment: If I need to specify in XAML, then I think it should be done this way
<ContentPresenter ContentSource = "Header" ContentTemplate = "{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" />

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I checked - it's solved! Thank you! :)
Please write your advice in the answers after I close the question.

Comment: Why I do not find this in the XAML template TabItem?

Comment: It's exactly what I see in the default windows 10 template for TabItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll bind that in the control template, probably just like this:

```
<ContentPresenter 
    ContentSource="Header"
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
    />
```